# Selecting Anniversary/Birthday in next month SQL

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

The code I'm using works until December.

```
Select * FROM [Date_Extension]
WHERE month(birthday) = month(getdate()) + 1
```

How do I add a `CASE` statement into this to select January when `month(getdate()) + 1 = 13`? Or should I be doing this a different way all together?

Answer (score 3):

Why not try a DatePart with the DateAdd?

```
SELECT * FROM [Data Extension] WHERE
DATEPART(mm,birthday) = DATEPART(mm,(DateAdd(m,1,GetDate()))
```

This will take the recipient's birthday month and match it to the following month

Comment: Thanks! This is great. I'm somewhat new to sql and learning on the go. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

Option 1:-If you "birthday" field set as DATE varchar

```
SELECT *, MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(dob, '%d-%m-%Y')) as Month FROM users WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(dob, '%d-%m-%Y')) = MONTH(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL + 30 DAY))
```

Option 2:-
If you "birthday" field set as DATE datatype

```
SELECT *, MONTH(dob) as Month FROM user WHERE MONTH(dob) = MONTH(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL + 30 DAY))
```